# Complex number in polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

Can anyone help me on how to find the coordinate and polar form of the following complex number
$$\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}}{1+i\sqrt{3}}\right)^{37}$$

I know that I need to find the magnitude and phase of it but I am unsure how to go about splitting it up into real and imaginary parts to find the phase. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For $z=r(\cos \theta+i \sin \theta)$ and $w=s( \cos \phi+i \sin \phi) \in \mathbb{C}$, recall that $\frac{z}{w}=\frac{r}{s} (\cos (\theta - \phi)+i \sin(\theta - \phi))$. Also, $z^n=r^n(\cos (n \theta)+i \sin (n \theta))$. Essentially, dividing and exponentiating complex numbers is easier if you have them in polar form. Now, how can you put your numerator and denominator in this form?

Comment: $2 \mbox{Re z} = z + \bar{z}$ and  $2i \mbox{Im z} = z - \bar{z}$

Answer (score 1):

The fraction is: $$\dfrac{\cfrac{\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}}2}{\cfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}2}=\frac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}4}}{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}3}}=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}{12}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

From the polar form of $z=re^{i\theta}$ one gets $z^{37}= r^{37}e^{37i\theta}$. So first find the inverse of $(1+i\surd3)$ multiply that with the numerator, then find the product's  polar form and then raise it to the 37th power.